# How do you add symbols for keyboard buttons?

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, typesetting, symbols

I'm creating my own keyboard shortcut cheat sheet in InDesign, and I'm struggling with how to add the keyboard button symbols.

For example, how can I add the symbols for Shift, and Command, to do something like this:

`⇧⌘A`

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking here. You just typed out (or copy-pasted) both symbols in your question – that’s how you do it in InDesign as well. Just type or copy-paste them; they’re just regular characters.

Comment: When I did this in InDesign, they show up as error symbols. That's why I wasn't sure if I was missing something.

Comment: That just means the font you’re using doesn’t have them. Change to a font that has these glyphs and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

### Fonts will not always include what you expect them to include.

As mentioned in the comments, you need a font which actually has the `⌘` and everything else you need. If you paste this `⌘` and it does not display with your selected font, you need to use another font.

Not every font out there includes these characters. Not every font out there will even include numbers and letters. There are fonts that only contain smileys for instance, or native american drawings, or traffic signs.

InDesign has a `Glyphs` panel which allows you to inspect the entire *font map*, basically a list of every character in a font. This is one way to quickly check if you have what you need in your font file.

- https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/how-to/add-accented-characters.html

Or, use a font that actually looks like keyboard buttons, for a more *visual* cheatsheet:

- https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/keycaps-deluxe?tab=glyphs
- https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/keystrokes?tab=glyphs
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/keystrokes-mt